# Understanding How Many Components to Include for PCA

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I've conducted a PCA on survey data and I'm confused about the concept of 'choosing how many principal components to include'.

When interpreting PC1, I found that it successfully captures the concept I'm interested in. It also accounts for a large proportion of the variation - 67%.

Interpreting the remaining components, I found they were interesting concepts, but they weren't concepts I had wanted to capture.

I often come across the concept of deciding how many components to 'include' in what I assume is a bid to capture as much variation in responses as possible. Given that I've interpreted these other components to be capturing different concepts than the desired one (as capture by PC1), why would I include these other components?

Ultimately, what I'm asking is:

- Even if my PC1 captured only 20% of the variation, if the other components capture a different concept then why would I combine the two components to produce scores for individual respondents?
- If one can successfully interpret the other components, even if they account for low variation, would it be feasible to use the component on its own to produce unit scores relating to that concept?

[image]

Comment: your PC2 seems to capture humping concept, with main factor being National, while pC3 is a local factor

Comment: @Aksakal Unfortunately this doesn't address the questions I outlined. My issue isn't explicitly with interpreting the components.

Comment: you mentioned concepts and seemed to imply that component selection is somehow related to interpretation of the components. that's one way to select components. there are other ways for other applications

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of an extended comment than an answer. First of all, it's not at all unusual for the first component in a PCA to capture a large percentage of the variance. Without rotation, this is a very common occurrence.

That said, your question is concerned with one aspect of the multitude of subjective decisions required in producing a PCA, any PCA. There are many possible methods and rules for selecting components, here are a few. Your preference for using component 'interpretability' can be considered a sanctioned one as it prioritizes human judgment over machine curation and decision-making. A second approach is to use a graphical heuristic, the so-called *scree* plot, which involves visually identifying a cut-off in a plot of eigenvalues and retaining those components falling before that threshold.

More machine or statistically curated rules are also used. For instance, retain those components with eigenvalues greater than 1.0, thereby ensuring that each component contributes at least as much as a single input variable. This rule is probably the most commonly used default on many software packages.

Yet another is to examine the change or difference from one eigenvalue to the next, again with an eye towards choosing components whose difference vs the prior eigenvalue is greater than 1.0. This is my personally preferred rule as it minimizes noisy, irrelevant components.

The point is that there is no hard and fast, cookbook *best* practice when it comes to choosing components in PCA. The choice is yours, just be ready to defend and explain the rule you choose.

Comment: Thank you! So even if a component explains 10% of the variation, I'm allowed to use it, and only it, to produce unit level scores for the concept I think it measures?

Comment: Bear in mind that *all* input variables have loadings (correlations) on each and every component. It is your interpretation of those loadings that abstracts them into a *concept*. This means that, given use of a dimension reducing decision rule and regardless of explanatory power, a component that captures a desired concept can be used to the exclusion of other information in the PCA. Again, just be ready to defend, explain and motivate your choices. It would also be a good idea to include a statement of the variance explained.

Comment: Understood, thank you! Lastly, would the fact that one component accounts for greater variation compared to another (e.g  PC1- 60% vs PC2- 20%) mean? Say, if PC1 measured individuals' level of trust in national and international governments but PC2 measured trust in only national governments, what do the component's respective variations mean?

Comment: Just one other consideration: sometimes we limit ourselves to the first $k$ components where $k$ is the number of parameters that can be safely estimated in the real model predicting $Y$ without overfitting.  That is the basis of incomplete principal component regression.

Comment: What does it mean if all of the components in a PCA model have extremely low explained inertia in each component? Eg. am using price lib MCA https://github.com/MaxHalford/prince#multiple-correspondence-analysis-mca and seeing PC w/ total inertia adding up to less than zero.